# Uncaught TypeError: FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one

Tags: javascript, gwt, braintree

I'm having a form that is simply not working as I try to make it ready for braintree in order to create a custom form for credit card information.

However, if I'm creating this form in the UiBinder:

```xml
<g:HTML ui:field="creditCardFormContainer">             
    <form id="credit-card-form" name="credit-card-form" action="/app/create-credit-card" method="post" target="hidden-iframe">

        <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
        <div id="card-number"/>

        <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
        <div id="cvv"/>

        <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
        <div id="expiration-date"/>

        <input id="nonce" name="nonce" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add credit card" />            
    </form>
</g:HTML>
```

and make a check of the type `credit-card-form` I'm actually seeing that it *isn't* the type I'm expecting it to be:

```
private native void setupCreditCardForm(String domId, String serverToken) /**/-{

    var form = $doc.getElementById(domId);

    if (form instanceof HTMLFormElement != true) {
        console.log(typeof(form)); // Prints 'object'
        throw new TypeError("Form must be of type HTMLFormElement"); // Gets thrown ..
    }

    // Never reached ..

    var bt = braintree;

    braintree.setup(
        serverToken,
        "custom",
        {
            id: domId,
            hostedFields: {
                number: {
                    selector: "#card-number"
                },
                cvv: {
                    selector: "#cvv"
                },
                expirationDate: {
                    selector: "#expiration-date"
                }
            },
            onPaymentMethodReceived: function(details) {
                this.@com.mz.client.admin.widget.paymentmethodinfo.PaymentMethodInfoView::onPaymentMethodReceived(Ljava/lang/String;)(details.nonce);
            }
        });
}-/**/;
```

Why is this the case? I'm clearly creating a `form` here - why is this not working out?

I'm doing it like [here](https://gist.github.com/allella/94c555b330859a62a710#file-braintree-php) as well as described in the [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration/javascript/v2).

*Removing* this check above would give me the following error coming from `braintree.setup()`:

```
FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`braintree` should be`$wnd.braintree`: if Braintree runs into hidden iframe gwt runs in, it cannot see the form through its ID. Passing the form's element might work, but Braintree should be injected into the "top window", not GWT's iframe.

Similarly, `instanceof` doesn't work because of iframe boundaries: use `$wnd.HTMLFormElement`.

Regarding the injection of the Braintree JavaScript code:

You might need to tell `ScriptInjector` to inject into the `TOP_WINDOW`. For example:

```java
braintreeJs = ScriptInjector.fromUrl(BRAINTREE_JS_URL).setCallback(
    new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception caught) {
            // ..
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            // ..
        }
    }).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
```

Comment: Hm, if I assign `var b = braintree` then `b` would be a valid object. If I use `$wnd.braintree` then there is not object. I'm using the `ScriptInjector` to load the braintree JavaScript file and so far the setup function is getting called. Not sure why `$wnd` is not working

Comment: You need to tell `ScriptInjector` to inject into the `TOP_WINDOW`. Or you could try passing the `form` element instead if the ID (depending on how well Braintree handles cross-window elements)

Comment: Omg thanks, that was it! After injecting into `TOP_WINDOW` it worked! I don't know if I would have ever had realized this on my own ..

Comment: What is BRAINTREE_JS_URL?