# Braintree - Hosted Fields - Uncaught TypeError: FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one

Tags: javascript, braintree

I am trying to customize the layout of my Braintree payment form using hosted fields.

However, I am getting an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one.
    at new n (braintree-2.32.1.min.js:4)
    at i._setupHostedFields (braintree-2.32.1.min.js:5)
    at new i (braintree-2.32.1.min.js:5)
    at braintree-2.32.1.min.js:5
    at braintree-2.32.1.min.js:3
    at c.<computed> (braintree-2.32.1.min.js:3)
    at configuration?authorizationFingerprint=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIwMTgwNDI2MTYtc2FuZGJveCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjU3NzE0MTgsImp0aSI6IjJmZmJkNTI5LWMzMDAtNDFhMi05ZjgwLWI0OTFiYWE1NTM4NCIsInN1YiI6InJka3I2dHd4N3dmeG5ucTQiLCJpc3MiOiJBdXRoeSIsIm1lcmNoYW50Ijp7InB1YmxpY19pZCI6InJka3I2dHd4N3dmeG5ucTQiLCJ2ZXJpZnlfY2FyZF9ieV9kZWZhdWx0IjpmYWxzZX0sInJpZ2h0cyI6WyJtYW5hZ2VfdmF1bHQiXSwib3B0aW9ucyI6e319.pW70SGcu6GctTeE7foNA_VxYRw-uuG2js0XVFOSTHWdGe2UNTQQ11X4mtGE-WuUL51nSDTXJu967_kjRAih5TA&_meta[sessionId]=8abf60fe-075c-48de-af80-7df0d446d515&callback=callback_jsonee1dbd210cde451fab3f2584ba12c0ba:1
```

I found a similar issue here [Uncaught TypeError: FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807955/uncaught-typeerror-formnapper-requires-an-htmlformelement-element-or-the-id-str) but this seems to be a different setup to what I am doing.

Here is the stripped down version of my payment form and the braintree.js file that I am using with it:

```js
$.ajax({
 url:'web/token.php',
 type:'get',
 dataType:'json',
 success:function(token){
  
  // braintree.setup(token,'dropin', {
   // container: 'dropin-container'
  // });
  
  braintree.setup(token,'custom', {
   id: 'payment_form',
   hostedFields:{
    number:{selector:'#card-number'},
    cvv:{selector:'#cvv'},
    expirationDate:{selector:'#expiration-date'}
   }
   // paypal:{
    // container: "paypal-container"
   // }
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<form action="process_order.php" method="POST" class="form" id="payment_form">
 <div id="payment_container">
 
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
   <div id="card-number" name="card-number"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
   <div id="cvv" name="cvv"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
   <div id="expiration-date" name="expiration-date"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!--<div id="paypal-container"></div>-->
  <!--<div id="dropin-container"></div>-->
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default mx-auto" value="Complete Order »" id="payment_button">
 </div>
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.31.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="web/braintree.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it the method is different, one is post another is get

Comment: @thj, no I don't think so, I GET the client token which is needed to set up the form which will later be POST-ed when a user completes it.

Comment: You are using the older Javascript v2 [Hosted Fields.](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/hosted-fields) Customization is also possible in the updated [Javascript v3 SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration/javascript/v3) Feel free to send further questions to support@braintreepayments.com. _Disclaimer: I work for Braintree_