# Submitting Braintree form after getting payment nonce using hosted fields

Tags: javascript, braintree

I am trying to customize the layout of my Braintree payment form using hosted fields.

I had been using the JS v2 SDK but was having other issues: [Braintree - Hosted Fields - Uncaught TypeError: FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474044/braintree-hosted-fields-uncaught-typeerror-formnapper-requires-an-htmlforme)

I've tried changing to the v3 SDK.

Here is the stripped down version of my payment form and the braintree.js file that I am using with it:

```js
$.ajax({
 url:'web/token.php',
 type:'get',
 dataType:'json',
 success:function(token){
  var payment_form = document.querySelector('#payment_form');
  var submit_button = document.querySelector('#payment_button');
  
  braintree.client.create({
   authorization: token
  }, function(err, clientInstance) {
   if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
   }
   
   braintree.hostedFields.create({
    client: clientInstance,
    styles: {
     'input': {'font-size': '14px'},
     'input.invalid': {'color': 'red'},
     'input.valid': {'color': 'green'}
    },
    fields: {
     number: {selector: '#card-number',placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'},
     cvv: {selector: '#cvv',placeholder: '123'},
     expirationDate: {selector: '#expiration-date',placeholder: 'MM/YY'}
    }
   }, function(err, hostedFieldsInstance) {
    if (err) {
     console.error(err);
     return;
    }
    
    submit_button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    payment_form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
      if (tokenizeErr) {
       console.error(tokenizeErr);
       return;
      }
      console.log('Got a nonce: ' + payload.nonce);
      $('#payment-method-nonce').val(payload.nonce);
            
      // payment_form.submit();
      // $('#payment_form').submit();
      document.getElementById('payment_form').submit();
     });
    });
   });
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<form action="process_order.php" method="POST" class="form" id="payment_form">
 <div id="payment_container">
 
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
   <div id="card-number" name="card-number"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
   <div id="cvv" name="cvv"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
   <div id="expiration-date" name="expiration-date"></div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="hidden" id="payment-method-nonce" name="payment-method-nonce">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default mx-auto" value="Complete Order »" id="payment_button">
 </div>
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.50.0/js/client.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.50.0/js/hosted-fields.min.js"></script>
<script src="web/braintree.js"></script>
```

At this point I can get the nonce and it is added to the value of the hidden input but the form won't submit.

When I use the variable name or use document.getElementById() I get `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function` but when I do it the jQuery way ($) nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried adding `var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');` to your braintree.js? 
_Disclaimer: I work at Braintree. Feel free to submit further questions to support@braintreepayments.com_

Comment: payment_form.submit();  should work.  Break at that point and inspect your object. It sounds like it is not a form.  Maybe you have more than one on the page.